# cqerlのcassandra_nodesオプションについて

Tags: erlang, cassandra

以下のリンクのcqerlを使っているのですが。（masterの最新を使用）

https://github.com/matehat/cqerl

ソースコード中で、以下のようにcassandraに接続し。

```
cqerl:new_client({host1, port1}, [])
```

ドキュメントに環境設定でcassandra_nodesを指定できると書いてあったので、以下のように指定しました。

```
rel/myapp/bin/myapp start -cqerl cassandra_nodes '[ { host1, port1 }, { host2, port2 },{ host3, port3 } ]'
```

しかし、cqerlはhost1しか知らないようでした（host1をダウンさせると、cqerlが接続先が見つからないというエラーを吐きます。）
cassandra_nodesを指定している際の、cqerl:new_clientの第一引数は何を指定すればいいのか、わかる方いらっしゃいますか？もしくはcassandra_nodesの設定のやり方が間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: すみません自己解決しました。
RASH REPORT Process <0.379.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: connection_closed in gen_fsm:terminate/7 line 611
CRASH REPORT Process <0.1493.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {connection_error,econnrefused} in gen_fsm:init_it/6 line 373

以上のようなエラーが出ていたのですが、おそらくこれが正しい反応で、移行もcqerl:new_client()にて作成したクライアントは正常に使用できました。

Answer (score 0):

すみません自己解決しました。

以下のようなエラーが出ていたのですが、おそらくこれが正しい反応で、移行も `cqerl:new_client()` にて作成したクライアントは正常に使用できました。

```
RASH REPORT Process <0.379.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: connection_closed in gen_fsm:terminate/7 line 611
CRASH REPORT Process <0.1493.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {connection_error,econnrefused} in gen_fsm:init_it/6 line 373
```

---

*この投稿は [@syuhei さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10705/cqerl%e3%81%aecassandra-nodes%e3%82%aa%e3%83%97%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment9850_10705) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*